# What is the difference between GPArotation package and nFactors for performing an Exploratory Factor Analysis?

Tags: r

A fellow researcher and I ran two different exploratory factor analyses using two different r packages (i.e. "GPARotation" and "nFactors") on the same dataset. However, we're receiving two starkly different results of what the optimal number of underlying factors are. ("GPARotation"= 4 factor solution & "nFactors" = 2 factor solution)

Both of our codes generated scree plots that indicated what the optimal number of factors. See code below:

```
install.packages('nFactors')
library(nFactors)
ev <- eigen(cor(df)) # get eigenvalues
ap <- parallel(subject=nrow(df),var=ncol(df),rep=100,cent=.05)
nS <- nScree(x=ev$values, aparallel=ap$eigen$qevpea)
plotnScree(nS)

install.packages('GPArotation')
library(GPArotation)
parallel <- fa.parallel(df, fm = 'minres', fa = 'fa')
fourfactor <- fa(df,nfactors = 4,rotate = "oblimin",fm="minres")
print(fourfactor)
print(fourfactor$loadings,cutoff = 0.3)
```

After performing a CFA using both the 2 and 4 factor models, we find that the 4-factor model has a slightly better fit than the 2 factor model.

However, I'm still needing to understand why the packages differ so much for future analyses.

Any information would quite helpful, thank you in advance!

Comment: This seems more like a question about interpreting the results from different statistical models rather than any specific programming question. As such it's probably a better fit for [stats.se] than Stack Overflow. Also you should include the results given that we can't run the code without input data.